# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 fails installation

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 for the first time, but while installing it fails for some reason. After trying multiple times, I couldnt find out why, I dont understand the fail report. It always failed when it was trying to install "grub on targeted disk" (or something like that).
I tried to re-flash the USB Boot drive and disconnect all hard disks, except the one I want as boot drive.
The drive I want to install ubuntu on, was a Windows boot drive before, could that be a problem? Although it said in the installation process, that it would format the disk.

[Picture of fail report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o740T.jpg)

Thank you in advance.